# Find out the range of a(75)

Tags: calculus

Given a sequence, a(1)=1,for n>1,a(n)=a(n-1)+1/a(n-1).prove that $12\lt a(75)\lt15$

My try is that at first I write a(n)-a(n-1)=1/a(n-1) then I put n=2,3,4,5.... 75 and add them.I got the expression a(75)=a(1)+1/a(1)+1/a(2)+1/a(3)+......1/a(74)  but now I am stuck.I suspect either I have to compare my expressions with some infinite GP or I have to use functional equations. Pls help me out

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look at $b(n) = a(n)^2 $

Comment: Yeah but in that case we get b(n)>4.Nothing more

Comment: What is the recursion for $b(n)$ in terms of $b(n-1)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Squaring the recursive relation we get

$$a_n^2 = a_{n-1}^2 + \frac{1}{ a_{n-1}^2} + 2 $$

From there we get $a_n^2 >  a_{n-1}^2 + 2$, and

$$ a_n^2 >  a_{n-1}^2 + 2 >  a_{n-2}^2 + 4 > \dots > a_1^2 + 2(n-1) = 2n-1$$

$$\Rightarrow a_n > \sqrt{2n-1} \Rightarrow a_{75} > \sqrt{149} > \sqrt{144} = 12 $$

Also, since $(a_n)$ is increasing sequence (by induction),

Then $a_n \geq 1$, and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{ a_{n-1}^2} \leq 1$ and we get

$$a_n^2=a_{n-1}^2 + \frac{1}{ a_{n-1}^2} + 2  \leq  a_{n-1}^2 +3 \leq a_{n-2}^2 + 6 \leq a_1^2 + 3(n-1) = 3n-2$$

$$\Rightarrow a_n \leq \sqrt{3n-2} \Rightarrow a_{75} \leq \sqrt{223} < \sqrt{225} = 15$$